# Why on earth won't this Javascript program run?

Tags: html

Just trying to make a simple calculator in javascript.  When I try to run it, nothing happens.  I assume its something really simple, but I just can't figure it out. Any ideas?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: Consider using jsfiddle.net for stuff like this. And indenting.

Comment: Why the `<!--` after `<script>`?

Comment: @Adam, it's an old technique to deal with ancient browsers that don't support scripting.  It prevents the script from showing up as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is malformed; missing a `/`. And you have closing html tags in the middle of all your stuff (instead of at the end). And you call CalcMortage and attach the results as the click handler, rather than the method itself (because of the closing `()` in `onclick = CalcMortgage();`). And you force multiple digits in the regex (like I can't put "5" for percentage).

[Other than that it's fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/CcwGL/)

Comment: Actually, he incorrectly has `</body></html>` at the end of his `<head>` section.

Comment: @Sparky672 Yep, that's the "closing html tag in the middle" of his stuff--edited to be more clear :)

Comment: I know you already mentioned it (I up-voted you too)... I was just being more specific about it.

Comment: I corrected the placement of both </body> and </html>.  The regex should look like var isdigit = /^[-]?[0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]+$/; ?  I try all of this and still no luck.

Comment: @Rich2233 Yeah, fix the rest of it, too. The fiddle I linked to works.

Comment: @Rich2233 - You also need to move the <script> section to the end of the document (it is usually to put it in a second <head> section). If you do not then the script will be run before the rest of the document is loaded, and the `getElementById` will fail. The regex should be changed to `/^[-]?[0-9]+[\.]?[0-9]*$/` (or similar) to allow single character input.

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning the return value (which is `undefined`) to the `onclick` handler right here:

```
document.getElementById("mortgageCalc").calculateMortgage.onclick = CalcMortgage ();
```

Try dropping the "call this function" parentheses:

```
document.getElementById("mortgageCalc").calculateMortgage.onclick = CalcMortgage;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a function call to `CalcMortgage` before you even define it:

```
document.getElementById("mortgageCalc").calculateMortgage.onclick = CalcMortgage ();
```

Consider putting this **after** the definiton of CalcMortgage:

```
document.getElementById("mortgageCalc").calculateMortgage.onclick = CalcMortgage;
```